# Loss function for generating from a convolutional neural network (TensorFlow)

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to create a convolutional network, followed by an RNN for video generation (next image in a sequence).

How can I specify the loss function for both of the networks? If the only thing my network learns is how to generate the next image in a series of images, I don't have a separate loss function for the CNN and the RNN. If I train the two networks jointly, (is that even possible with TF?), wouldn't that slow down the training immensely? Any ideas how to specify the loss function in this case?